# Keep dictionary elements order the same in AWS Rekognition outputs in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, image-processing, amazon-rekognition

I am using AWS rekognition to study emotion outputs. This is my code:

```
photo = 'InVacation.jpg'

image = Image.open(photo)
stream = io.BytesIO()
image.save(stream,format="JPEG")
image_binary = stream.getvalue()

response = client.detect_faces(
    Image={'Bytes':image_binary},
    Attributes=['ALL']
    )
response
```

The problem is that every time I process multiple photos, the order of emotion types changes. For example:

```
response['FaceDetails'][0]["Emotions"]

[{'Type': 'DISGUSTED', 'Confidence': 3.6973443031311035},
 {'Type': 'HAPPY', 'Confidence': 1.150834321975708},
 {'Type': 'ANGRY', 'Confidence': 4.140467643737793},
 {'Type': 'CALM', 'Confidence': 70.42333221435547},
 {'Type': 'CONFUSED', 'Confidence': 9.918739318847656},
 {'Type': 'SAD', 'Confidence': 4.620922565460205},
 {'Type': 'SURPRISED', 'Confidence': 6.048351764678955}]
```

Using the same code, the second photo yields:

```
[{'Type': 'SAD', 'Confidence': 4.620922565460205},
 {'Type': 'ANGRY', 'Confidence': 4.140467643737793},
 {'Type': 'CONFUSED', 'Confidence': 9.918739318847656},
 {'Type': 'CALM', 'Confidence': 70.42333221435547},
 {'Type': 'DISGUSTED', 'Confidence': 3.6973443031311035},
 {'Type': 'HAPPY', 'Confidence': 1.150834321975708},
 {'Type': 'SURPRISED', 'Confidence': 6.048351764678955}]
```

In the first trial, the order of output is: Disgusted, happy ... Surprised. However, in the second trial, the order changes to: Sad, angry ... Surprised.

The changes in the order output become a problem because I want to loop through multiple photos and store the `confidence` values in a set of rows. For instance:

```
FaceEmotions = pd.DataFrame(response['FaceDetails'][0]["Emotions"])
awsConfidence = FaceEmotions[["Confidence"]].T
awsConfidence.columns = ["Surprised", "Happy", "Calm", "Sad", "Disgusted", "Angry", "Confused"]
awsConfidence

           Surprised     Happy       Calm       Sad Disgusted      Angry    Confused
Confidence  3.697344  6.048352  70.423332  4.620923  1.150834   9.918739    4.140468
Confidence  5.623224  3.032444  40.413132  6.420921  2.400834   1.118739    7.140412
And so on...
```

What setting would I have to change in the `boto3` module to keep constant the order types on output?

Comment: Try `collections.OrderedDict`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have consistent data frames with pandas by sorting the values by Type then transposing and setting the correct index :

```
#Supposing x is the array you get
df1 = pd.DataFrame(x).sort_values(by='Type').\
    set_index('Type').T.reset_index().drop('index', axis= 1)
```

you can then concatenate the data frames you generate with ease:

```
dfc = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try it tonight.